# AngularJS - How can I do a redirect with a full page load?

Tags: angularjs, routes

I want to do a redirect that does a full page reload so that the cookies from my web server are refreshed when the page loads. `window.location = "/#/Next"` and `window.location.href = "/#/Next"` don't work, they do an Angular route which does not hit the server.

What is the correct way to make a full server request within an Angular controller?

Comment: did you ever solve this?

Comment: did you ever solve this?

Comment: did you ever solve this?

Comment: did you ever solve this?

Comment: did you ever solve this?

Comment: did you ever solve this?

Comment: check this https://stackoverflow.com/a/50987755/6868227

Comment: With plain JS this works in FF and Chrome:
document.location.assign(<url>);
location.reload(true);

Comment: did you ever solve this?

Answer (score 185):

**For `<a>` tags**:

You need to stick `target="_self"` on your `<a>` tag

There are three cases where AngularJS will perform a full page reload:

- Links that contain target element
  Example: `<a href="/ext/link?a=b" target="_self">link</a>`
- Absolute links that go to a different domain
  Example: `<a href="http://angularjs.org/">link</a>`
- Links starting with '/' that lead to a different base path when base is defined
  Example: `<a href="/not-my-base/link">link</a>`

**Using javascript**:

The `$location` service allows you to change only the URL; it does not allow you to reload the page. When you need to change the URL and reload the page or navigate to a different page, please use a lower level API: `$window.location.href`.

See:

- https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/$location
- https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$location

Comment: I'm doing this in a controller, not html.

Comment: $window.location.href does the same thing that window.location.href does. I'm pretty sure $window is just a wrapping service for window. Either way both do an Angular route instead of the full page refresh.

Comment: $window.location.href definitely causes a full page refresh, I'm doing it in my app.

Comment: From the docs on $location: "What does it not do?
It does not cause a full page reload when the browser URL is changed. To reload the page after changing the URL, use the lower-level API, $window.location.href."

Comment: I've read the same thing. Doesn't work in the current version of Chrome. It does an Angular route.

Comment: I'm using AngularJS 1.0.6 with the latest Chrome, it's working great. What version of AJS are you on?

Comment: 1.0.6 from the CDN. I'm doing this within an $http.post success callback, if that matters, though I've tried it outside of the callback and gotten the same results. If I do the redirect to "/" (which I have an Angular route defined for as well), it works with the full page refresh, but "/#/Next" just does the view change.

Comment: Might help then if you put together a JSfiddle for inspection, and update your question. I can't reproduce the issue.

Comment: have you tried `location =location.href+ "/#next"` ? or suitable variation that strips any hashes

Comment: Same result. Angular route.

Comment: how about `meta no-cache` tag? Seems very strange that angular is intercepting `window.location`

Comment: `<a href="..." target="_self">` is what worked for me. thanks !

Comment: location.href alone does not work if it is same url with just different hash.

Comment: To anyone stuck, the `destinationUrl` must contain the `http://` prefix, or it will open ww.yourcurrenturl.com/destinationurl

Comment: i couldn't get any of them work, until i tried target _self option mentioned above.

Comment: Is there a way to do the analogous of `<a href="/link" target="_self">` but in javascript? I tried to use window and $window but it always goes to an Angular route (I am using html5mode). I want to go to www.my-app-base-url/link sending the request to the server.

Answer (score 33):

We had the same issue, working from JS code (i.e. not from HTML anchor). This is how we solved that:

1. If needed, *virtually* alter current URL through `$location` service. This might be useful if your destination is just a variation on the current URL, so that you can take advantage of `$location` helper methods. E.g. we ran `$location.search(..., ...)` to just change value of a querystring paramater.
2. Build up the new destination URL, using current `$location.url()` if needed. In order to work, this new one had to include everything after schema, domain and port. So e.g. if you want to move to:

`http://yourdomain.example/YourAppFolder/YourAngularApp/#/YourArea/YourAction?culture=en`

then you should set URL as in:

`var destinationUrl = '/YourAppFolder/YourAngularApp/#/YourArea/YourAction?culture=en';`

(with the leading `'/'` as well).

1. Assign new destination URL at *low-level*: `$window.location.href = destinationUrl;`
2. Force reload, still at low-level: `$window.location.reload();`

Comment: This doesn't work for me in Angular 1.3.1 with Chrome 38. The value of $window.location.href does not change when I assign a path or a full URL. Only $window.location.assign() worked for me.

Comment: Having the same problems as Felix, solved it in a different way http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31137809/setting-window-location-href-not-working-as-expected

Answer (score 13):

After searching and giving hit and trial session I am able to solove it by first specifying url like

```
$window.location.href = '/#/home/stats';
```

then reload

```
$window.location.reload();
```

Comment: This seems to fix the issue, but clicking back and forward on the browser will cause a lot of inconsistencies.

Answer (score 9):

I had the same issue. When I use `window.location`, `$window.location` or even `<a href="..." target="_self">` the route does not refresh the page. So the cached services are used which is not what I want in my app. I resolved it by adding `window.location.reload()` after `window.location` to force the page to reload after routing. This method seems to load the page twice though. Might be a dirty trick, but it does the work. This is how I have it now:

```
  $scope.openPage = function (pageName) {
      window.location = '#/html/pages/' + pageName;
      window.location.reload();
  };
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
$window.location.href="#page-name";
$window.location.reload();
```