# Why does AngularJS break self-referencing anchor links?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

If you're at a location like this...

```
http://www.domain.com/index.html
```

... and you have a link that points to the same location...

```
<a href="/index.html">My Link</a>
```

... then clicking on the link does nothing. Normally you would be redirected to the page as normal; a handy way to refresh the page (without doing a full refresh).

I've traced the culprit of this odd behaviour to AngularJS.

Observe the following example:

```
<body>
    <a href="">Sample Link</a>

    <script>
        var SampleApp = angular.module("SampleApp", []);
    </script>
</body>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/7vqD9/

By clicking on the link the browser tries to go to the same location (because of a blank href). **This is normal**.

Now let's activate Angular:

```
<body ng-app="SampleApp">
    <a href="">Sample Link</a>

    <script>
        var SampleApp = angular.module("SampleApp", []);
    </script>
</body>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/7bEp3/

Clicking on the link does nothing.

Why does AngularJS break links in this way? Is there any obvious reason that I'm missing?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/16003013/1085699 should give you the answer you are looking for

Comment: Perfect. Adding `target="_self"` does the trick.

Comment: @RowanFreeman this is what I have done also. Works like a charm.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Why does Angular prevent classic behavior of `href`?**

From [Mastering web component with AngularJs](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1782161821):

> AngularJS comes pre-bundled with the a directive, which prevents
>   default actions on links when the href attribute is omitted. This
>   allows us to create clickable elements using the a tag and the
>   ng-click directive. For example, we can invoke the `a`tag as follows:
>
> ```
> <a ng-click='showFAQ()'>Frequently Asked Questions</a>
> ```
>
> **Having the a tags without a default navigation action is handy, as
>   several CSS frameworks use the a tags to render different types of
>   visual elements, where a navigation action doesn't make much sense.**
>   For example the Twitter's Bootstrap CSS framework uses the a tags to
>   render headers in tabs and accordion components.

Keyword to retain is:  "handy"

Answer (score 1):

Angular overrides the `a` tag: https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/ng/directive/a.js

The lines to note here are:

```
      // if we have no href url, then don't navigate anywhere.
      if (!element.attr('href')) {
        event.preventDefault();
      }
```

Angular does this because of [`ngHref`](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive%3angHref), which sets the `href` only after angular and scope are fully loaded, thus preventing the user from accidentally going to `/{{pageUrl}}/`.

If you want to reload the page, you should look at the `$location` service provided by Angular.