# setting window.location.href not working as expected

Tags: javascript, angularjs

If the user is at url **foo.com/#/veryLongToken** and the `response.redirectUrl` is **foo.com/#/veryLongToken/resultToken** , in the first example, when the page is reloaded we end up at **foo.com/#/veryLongToken**.
In the second example, we end up at **foo.com/#/veryLongToken/resultToken** which is what we expect.

More info;

- The URL is very long
- AngularJS window-wrapper $window is used
- Tested in Chrome and Safari, both displaying same behaviour

Doesn't work:

```
function successHandler(response) {
   $window.location.href = response.redirectUrl;
   /* redirectUrl might contain only changes to the hash-fragment
      which is why we force a reload here */
   $window.location.reload();
}
```

Works;

```
function successHandler(response) {
   $window.location.hash = response.redirectUrl.substr(response.redirectUrl.indexOf('#'));
   $window.location.reload();
}
```

I'd really like to know why the first example doesn't work. Any ideas?

UPDATE:
`$window.location.href` is https://foo.fo.se/#/payment/Ak1ZWDg1MDhJAwJWVElOUE5WVEZQSQMCAwIDAgMCAwIDAgMCTVlYODUwOEkDAgMCAwIDHQDSqdsSYXcT5rdNEkrClAYdawRZXF3vwZUSSb9_XHeQTFJcyJxnQXnz1V4gQCTgm7q9OYmLKMFVEaCaZM8RX6iIExvQZT7uPjtfYowjvvU-JpO8yMhTquehcBOo_JEXqCskKVStCp25qWq4GdPXgP3f1KthAO17OOAdLHKMNm8bmNW8Nj-P_xltDTV22ZHABQS_4d0DcWSDj7ZfUK3q28zZ9pLdedu3sjblzmXqDiSBNEuDQfQOjMt_s0xlayYX0qUwJwwviaZ8aB-qLRnV7KD_LvaESGrtwq7_iiNIoB1jeFAp0dSG_N1c-5V-VZ3100DbJBoecTIF4NaCS62IxfM

`response.redirectUrl` is

https://foo.fo.se/#/payment/AkpITDg0ODFIAwIwTDNWVkwzMzcwSgMCAwIDAgMCAwIDAgMCSkhMODQ4MUgDAgMCAwIDHTQ1Z7gveX-CH7OzdVcAtOtar9mOZQF8f4t7MFIM5b1_WU7BAEtYPfSD77sFsGmHnm4GoFMmsIHUCzscUiaP2iofV7rflegQADTieSpwbausFLn6FNmaVeZdlFEtoWr6cU1VlN09zqk4T-1cqheoDsb_jMWr3kTdZGkJh_168P99zjV324jpDIkKAZ12WFXuaphnGdNoJgP9Ka9S2aIi8LniCiJNtOq-iXL4w8JNYVyLrbOqB2QNpc__RtT5kcW9NEaPWehQx2S5CIB157RcI_WkeGJRb1DKSSuy8CFIYJVrEOlCb-GtZ9gmPhrLh6qPiumokJWSI2cUuFBDpaGAeiA/AkpITDg0ODFIAwJJTlRFUk5BTF9FUlJPUgMCAwIDAgJJTlRFUk5BTF9QUk9DRVNTX0RFQklUX05PTl9SRUNPVkVSQUJMRQMD

Comment: try $location.path('url') but dont forget to add it to your Conroller .controller('blaCtrl', function ($location){}

Comment: my understanding of $location is that it's just a higher level service than $window, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16002984/angularjs-how-can-i-do-a-redirect-with-a-full-page-load , or do you have more information?

Answer (score 0):

As a # in a URL mark an anchor, the changing of it don't trigger a page load as your bas url (foo.com/) stay the same. The window.location.href isn't ment to hadle anchor change.

If you whant to change the "anchor" part, you must use the window.location.hash for it to be detected (as in your second exemple)

Comment: Understood, but if I change it anyways, and then do window.location.reload() afterwards, it is my understanding that it should work anyways? See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10612438/javascript-reload-the-page-with-hash-value

Comment: The js specification don't force it (the # change detection in href) so it's up to every browser implementation. As the hash filed is avaialble for this, it's understandable they don't allow it in the href. After, maybe angular do some stuff there, i don't know enoght in angular to answer more.

Answer (score -1):

Every browser has a URL length limits! the shortest one is *Internet Explorer which is 2083 characters!* Check it out [here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/208427)

And all *webkit browsers Chrome, Safari, Mozilla has a limit of 100KB*! You can get more details [here](https://technomanor.wordpress.com/2012/04/03/maximum-url-size/)

Comment: Thanks for the info. I think in this case, that the URL is definetly within the allowed length.

Comment: Can you share the actual URL so that we can get better insight of the problem!

Comment: Sure, here's the actual URL:
https://foo.fo.se/#/payment/Ak1ZWDg1MDhJAwJWVElOUE5WVEZQSQMCAwIDAgMCAwIDAgMCTVlYODUwOEkDAgMCAwIDHQDSqdsSYXcT5rdNEkrClAYdawRZXF3vwZUSSb9_XHeQTFJcyJxnQXnz1V4gQCTgm7q9OYmLKMFVEaCaZM8RX6iIExvQZT7uPjtfYowjvvU-JpO8yMhTquehcBOo_JEXqCskKVStCp25qWq4GdPXgP3f1KthAO17OOAdLHKMNm8bmNW8Nj-P_xltDTV22ZHABQS_4d0DcWSDj7ZfUK3q28zZ9pLdedu3sjblzmXqDiSBNEuDQfQOjMt_s0xlayYX0qUwJwwviaZ8aB-qLRnV7KD_LvaESGrtwq7_iiNIoB1jeFAp0dSG_N1c-5V-VZ3100DbJBoecTIF4NaCS62IxfM (the **redirectUrl** is this URL + a slash and another token)