# ng-route I want to be redirect to the server when route is missing from $routeProvider

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-mvc, single-page-application, ngroute, route-provider

I've got an asp.net MVC application and I'm trying to apply mini-spas

My angular js setp:

```
appNg.config(function ($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
$routeProvider
    .when("/AccountManager/UserLogin", {
        templateUrl: "/App_ng/AccountManager/Views/AccountManagerUserLoginView.html",
        controller: "accountManagerUserLoginController",
    })
    .when("/AccountManager/UserSignup", {
        templateUrl: "/App_ng/AccountManager/Views/AccountManagerUserSignupView.html",
        controller: "accountManagerUserSignupController",
    });

$locationProvider.html5Mode(true);

console.log("Config.Complete: appNg");
```

});

my baseref in _layoutpage in head tag (at the top)

```
   <base href="/" />
```

my links on layoutpage:

```
WORKING:
<a href="/AccountManager/UserSignup"><i class="fa fa-sign-in"></i> <span>ng UserSignup</span></a>
<a href="/AccountManager/UserLogin"><i class="fa fa-sign-in"></i> <span>ng UserLogin</span></a>
<a href="http://cnn.com"><i class="fa fa-sign-in"></i> <span>CNN.COM</span></a>
NOT WORKING:
<a href="/AngTestRoute/about2"><i class="fa fa-sign-in"></i> <span>ng About2</span></a>
```

The first 3 links work as expected, but the last link does not, the address in the browser url bar changes, but the page stays the same.

I want angular to ignore the route and let me call the server to get a new page, so that I can load the new page with embedded the mini-spa related to the new address. Since the address that is not working is not present in the $routeProvider routes, I was hoping that angular would have not filtered the address. How can I solve the issue?

Yes, I know I can use target _blank on the a tag but this can't be done (from my trials), since this will create issues with links that should be filtered by angular when in a specific mini-spa.

I've also read [AngularJS - How can I do a redirect with a full page load?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16002984/angularjs-how-can-i-do-a-redirect-with-a-full-page-load) without any success.

Answer (score 0):

This one bites me pretty frequently. We use ui-router, but I think ngRoute is the same. Try `target="_self"` in your anchor tag.

```
<a target="_"self" href="/AngTestRoute/about2"><i class="fa fa-sign-in"></i> <span>ng About2</span></a>
```

Glancing at some of my own projects, I think I also use the fully qualified url, and not just the path. So maybe

```
<a target="_"self" href="http://myserver/mybasepath/AngTestRoute/about2"><i class="fa fa-sign-in"></i> <span>ng About2</span></a>
```