# How an application will support Asp.net-MVC routing and angular 2 routing both

Tags: asp.net-mvc, angular

I am creating an application in Asp.Net-MVC in VS2015. I want that application should support MVC routing and Angular 2 routing both.

> I need MVC routing for Menu bar and Angular 2 routing for wizard
>   present in each page lie below image.

[image: Wizard]

I have gone through various articles and finally used below code in my RouteConfig.cs file:

```
 routes.MapRoute(
            name: "spa-fallback",
            url: "{*url}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index" }
            );
```

But this is not working properly. When i go from Home/Index to Home/Contact, it should not consider the angular 2 routing . But it is considering the angular 2 routing and showing the error :

> Error: Cannot match any routes: 'Home/Contact'(…)

Below is screenshot:

[image: Erros]

How could i made the application compatible with both routings. Thanks

Comment: How do you redirect to this route? Click a url, type in the browser, etc.?

Comment: I have an anchor tag .. <a href = "/Home/Contact">Contact</a> on my index page...Page is redirecting to the Contact page but the console have an error when the contact page render..

Comment: I think you need to use the full URL like http://..../Home/Contact

Comment: Alternatively check here: it's for Angular 1, but it might do the trick in Angular2 as well: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16002984/angularjs-how-can-i-do-a-redirect-with-a-full-page-load. The problem you have is that angular2 interprets the a tag and override it. You need to prevent angular from doing it.

Answer (score 2):

There could be a workaround like already described in the answer to this question: [How to use ASP.NET MVC and AngularJS routing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23682203/how-to-use-asp-net-mvc-and-angularjs-routing)

So, in short, define a route that would catch urls intended for mvc controllers for sure, i.e. add a prefix

```
routes.MapRoute(
        name: "spa-fallback",
        url: "app/{*url}",
        defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index" }
);
```