# AngularJS How to reload then redirect to another view?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, location, reload, ng-view

I'm trying to make some button disappear when I logout, but if I don't put reload command It won't reload and button wouldn't disappear. After I put reload command view doesn't change because the process end at reload line.

Here my code :

```
$scope.logout = function(){
    deleteCookie("Username","/");
    location.reload();
    $location.path('/view1');


}
```

Please help !

UPATE: app.js

```
'use strict';

// Declare app level module which depends on views, and components
angular.module('myApp', [
  'ngRoute',
  'myApp.view1',
  'myApp.view2',
  'myApp.viewLogin',
  'myApp.SaveCafeDetail',
  'myApp.viewUserprofile',
  'myApp.viewManageuser',
  'myApp.viewEditcafe',
  'myApp.version'
]).
config(['$locationProvider', '$routeProvider', function($locationProvider, $routeProvider) {
  $locationProvider.hashPrefix('!');

  $routeProvider.otherwise({redirectTo: '/view1'});
}]);
```

Comment: put the deleteCookie in if else tag

Comment: @AyanAman Does that cause the problem ?

Comment: how you are disappearing button??

Comment: see the answer @KitsakornP

Comment: Possible duplicate of [AngularJS - How can I do a redirect with a full page load?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16002984/angularjs-how-can-i-do-a-redirect-with-a-full-page-load)

Answer (score 0):

You can use **absolute url** or just add `target="_self"` on your `<a>` tag, if you use it in your HTML.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest this approach..

```
     $scope.logout = function(){
     deleteCookie("Username","/");

        if (-----)  {   //deletecokkie value is null 
       window.location = "http://.../..."  //full URL of the designation;
          }

    }
```

Comment: Thanks for reply, I add $stat but error shows up Unknown provider: $stateProvider <- $state <- Logincontroller Do I have to setup some thing in my app.js ?

Comment: I have update my question above thank you so much for helping sir !

Comment: $stateProvider wont work for you because you are not using it. i have updated my answer please see that

Comment: Thanks for helping, but window.location only change view. No reload happen :(

Comment: you dont need to reload the whole page without any reason.. if you wanted to hide the button just make the button hide when you are clicking on logout

Answer (score 0):

To reload to another view, simply use:

```
$state.go("your_view_name");
```

Hope this helps!