# angularjs normal navigation instead of $location.path

Tags: javascript, angularjs

in controller A I do `$location.path('/home')`, but actually I want a normal redirect. $location.path does not reload the page. I know in ui-route there's `$state.go({reload:true})`, but how to do it with normal ngRoute? I do

```
.controller('home', function($route){
$route.reload()
}
```

I got an infinite loop.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16002984/angularjs-how-can-i-do-a-redirect-with-a-full-page-load

Comment: Provide some code. So that problem can be found.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the window object to reload instead of `$location.path('/path');`:

```
window.location = '/path';
```

If you want to use ngRoute, you can reload the page on routeChange:

```
myApp.run(['$route', '$rootScope', function ($route, $rootScope) {
    return $rootScope.$on('$routeChangeStart', function (event, next, current) {
        $route.reload();
    });
}]);
```

Answer (score 0):

First why you want reload the page while location change in navigation?. I think we don't need reload() on location change.

you are given $route.reload() as on-fly function. The controller execute while navigate and check on-fly function and run $route.reload();. so the route is reload and again the controller initiate, and again execute on-fly function $route.reload();. so the reload is going infinity.

You can try $route.reload in function ng-click as per need. don't use reload() function as on-fly function.

Example.

```
$scope.saveData = function(){
 //some save functionality and reload the route
$route.reload();
}

<button ng-click="saveData">Save</button>
```

Comment: uh? if I use your code in controller A, it will reload itself, it won't go anywhere.

Comment: yep Jamie I knew. I said that point of way only. Why we need to reload the page while $location.path();. Automatically controller get load while change the route.