# angularjs route to match $window.location

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I want to reload the page with different html page using angularjs `$window`, the documation says:

> Page reload navigation
>   The $location service allows you to change only the URL; it does not allow you to reload the page. When you need to change the URL and reload the page or navigate to a different page, please use a lower level API, $window.location.href.

So I set the loaction to the page `$window.location.href = '/transaction';`

and the matching route on `config` block:

```
app.config(function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider
    .when('/transaction', {
        templateUrl : 'JavaScript/directives/modelHTML/Transaction.html',
        controller : 'endProcessModelController'
    });
});
```

But instrad of Transaction.html page I get Error `404: SRVE0190E: File not found: /transaction` with the route `mydomain.com/UI/transaction`.

BTW - templateUrl url's works fine in other place like UImodel so the problam is the navigation I think.

Comment: Please refer stackoverflow link : [angularjs-how-can-i-do-a-redirect-with-a-full-page-load](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16002984/angularjs-how-can-i-do-a-redirect-with-a-full-page-load)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the location to the page `$window.location.href = '#/transaction';` .
`'#'` indicating location the startpage which is normally index.html. so the link will be `index.html#/transaction`.Since its a single page app

i think in your config do

```
'/UI/transaction'  instead of  `/transaction`
```

and in the link do `$window.location.href = '#/UI/transaction'`

Comment: included angular-ui-route ?

Comment: It works for me always  are you doing something the wrong way ?

Comment: like? I posted the all process. is the more code needed?

Comment: what do you get when you try  mydomain.com#/transaction

Comment: Now i think your index is at mydomain.com. so  go to  the config and instead of '/transaction' use /UI/transaction

Comment: Then in the link use '#/UI/transaction'

Comment: okay then Good luck just  consider upvoting it so that it helps someone else

Answer (score 0):

Try this

`$location.path($window.location.origin +'/transaction');`

And if you feel all the routes have something extra after the origin you can set a `<base href="...">` for that and tell angular from where to take the rest amount of text for route purpose.

If you redirect the page with `your_origin/transaction` your browser will make a request to the server of `/transaction`, which the server will be not able to understand and 404 will come. But the route is client side (browser) routeing, so If you are routing to route `/abc` your javascript code is interpreting that, and invokes the corrosponding operations, (might be a different call to server for the html template or some data dependency, and then instantiating the controller and attach to view). So the moment you are trying to route  your javascript code should be loaded.

Either you go for a ui-router where the route comes after `#` and this allow the browser to play after the text of (`#`) and not to reloading.

Or, make your server such a way, If a unidentified request comes you should return the base (index) page, so it will load all the scripts and that js will do the rest. (But obviously you will loose all the existing data in that state)

Answer (score 0):

Is the `mydomain.com/UI/transaction` address  correct (you use html5 mode)?

Does the problem occur when you try to enter directly into `mydomain.com/UI/transaction`?

If so, the problem is wrong server configuration (eg .htaccess file).